# Countif with EOMONTH

Tags: excel

EOMONTH doesn't include end of month days with time stamp format

I am doing a countifs, with EOMONTH and the last day of the month dates with time stamp format is not being counted. How can I get around this issue? For example 4/30/2019  2:56:00 PM is not count

```
COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,">="&Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,"<="&EOMONTH(Sheet1!B2,0))
```

```
B2=4/1/19
A12:A4
4/30/19 2:43 AM
4/30/19 2:43 AM
4/30/19 2:43 AM
```

I would expect this formula to return a count of 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOMONTH returns a date without time.  `4/30/2019 00:00:00`.  so being less than or equal will not return true for `4/30/19 2:43 AM` as it is greater.

Use

```
"<"&EOMONTH(Sheet1!B2,0)+1
```

Which now asks if it less then `05/01/2019 00:00:00`.

Like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,">="&Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,"<"&EOMONTH(Sheet1!B2,0)+1)
```

[image: ]]